# BinaryWriter write bytes from TextBox

Tags: c#, binarywriter

I have been trying to make a test program, that writes a byte from a textbox to an offset in another textbox.

I have been trying to do that:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName)))
{
     bw.Seek(toolStripTextBox1.Text, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     bw.Write((byte)textBox1.Text);
}
```

`toolStripTextBox1` contains the offset where I want to write and `textBox1` contains the bytes I want to write.

Let's say I typed in the `toolStripTextBox1` `"0xF450B0"` and in `textBox1` `"1052"`, I wanted it to write the location at `"0xF450B0"` to this: http://gyazo.com/49afd54dfc54fc15be47a7e08f300960

Comment: Is it a hacking attempt?

Comment: Nope, not a hacking attempt since I don't hack. I want to write Hexadecimal data into a ROM, if you don't know what ROM is, you better search in google.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the offset (hex) to an integer if that is *always* what the user enters. That looks like:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(ofd.FileName)))
{
     bw.Seek(Convert.ToInt32(toolStripTextBox1.Text, 16), SeekOrigin.Begin);
     bw.Write((byte)textBox1.Text);
}
```

Just to emphasize - if the user enters something that is not hexidecimal into `toolStripTextBox1` you will get an exception. You could use `Int32.TryParse` if this is a scenario you need to handle. For more information on the conversion between hex and integer see [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz6z5ks(v=vs.110).aspx).

Best of luck!